# get printed value after execution of os command python

Tags: android, python, gradle, operating-system

I am running the following function in python where a user is prompted for a password and the an os.system command is run with the password as an argument :

```
    password = raw_input("Please enter keystore password\n")
    gradle_command = "./gradlew assemble" + flavor_name + "release  -Pprop=\"['" + password + "']\""
    try:
        os.chdir("../")
        os.system(gradle_command)
    except OSError:
        sys.exit("Error building apk,")
```

The problem is that the except never gets called. If the user types in the wrong password the gradle command executes and prints BUILD FAILED.

What i want to know is how i can register that the build has failed to exit the script accordingly. is there a way i can grab the BUILD_FAILED printed value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works fine, have just checked.

Comment: did you simulate a failed execution of the gradle command?

Comment: Yes, have throw `RuntimeException` inside. Tried with wrapper as well.

Comment: I wasnt getting a runtime exception. i was getting the following: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageFlavorRelease'. I found a work around for it. posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. A failed gradle execution will return a non zero number so i can do the following:

```
 password = raw_input("Please enter keystore password\n")
 gradle_command = "./gradlew assemble" + flavor_name + "release  -Pprop=\"['" + password + "']\""
 if os.system(gradle_command) is not 0:
    sys.exit("Error building apk")
```